# For loop variable declaration for the condition in .NET Source code

Tags: c#, .net

I've been digging through [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b893f78d65cc65062a34d61dcac19a2399571ae1/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionVisitor.cs) in `.NET` and I found this `for` loop,

```
for (int i = 0, n = nodes.Count; i < n; i++) 
{
    Expression node = Visit(nodes[i]);
    if (newNodes != null) 
    {
        newNodes[i] = node;
    } 
    else if (!object.ReferenceEquals(node, nodes[i])) 
    {
        newNodes = new Expression[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            newNodes[j] = nodes[j];
        }
        newNodes[i] = node;
    }
}
```

Now is there any particular reason why is that: `i = 0, n = nodes.Count; i < n`?

Is there any performance gain from this that is not in `i = 0; i < nodes.Count`?

Comment: In this loop n is used too and for counting node's count only one time in the beginning and not at the each iteration i think this is better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is best practice to use a variable when you use the same statement more than once.

Here, `nodes.Count` is used in two places as below and hence, variable was used instead of executing the same statement twice.

```
for (int i = 0, n = nodes.Count; i < n; i++) {
```

And,

```
newNodes = new Expression[n];
```

Note: As discussed in the comments, performance difference is completely negligible though.

Comment: While you aren't wrong, I feel like in this case the performance difference is completely negligible.

Comment: @Abion47 it depends what is happening in the Count property. If counts the elements on every call it is NOT negligible, if the property returns global variable which was calculated the count on the creation of the object is negligible. For example with List<T> count you don't have a problem.

Comment: @Abion47 Yes you are right :-). it's a code best practice so that if you rename the nodes, you don't need to rename the same in multiple places though Visual studio will do this for you. In case what will happen if you edit it directly in the source control such as `GitHub` and `BitBucket`.

Comment: @Abion47: For most code you'd be right, but Roslyn has quite strict performance requirements. They even care about the allocation cost of an enumerator. As one of the RyuJIT team members noted recently, the .NET JIT wouldn't inline property accesses for a long time, so at the very least you pay for the method call when accessing it, which is also virtual. The compiler also can't know that nodes is immutable here so common subexpression elimination would not be performed. It's also common style throughout the Roslyn codebase, I'd presume, so might be negligible here, but matter in other places.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has any much performance effects in this case. But as they are using this `n` is this line as well,

`newNodes = new Expression[n];`

So,

- Program has to get `node.Count` only once.
- `n` need not to be assigned again.
- Looks much cleaner.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: How does it have not any performance effects if it calculates node.count one time instead of calculating at each iteration of the loop???

Comment: Those are initial conditions, they are executed only once. It won't set `i=0` for each loop.

Comment: i know and said it, and as you said "I don't think it has any performance effects." but it's performance effect that count is calculating only once instead of calculating at the each iteration if the loop was written only with i = 0; i < nodes.Count

Comment: I think its negligible. Also, I forgot to add `much`.

Comment: It depends on how the count is being calculated.

Comment: Yes it is quite possible. He did not understand why it was done and specifically in this case, it may not affect the speed of the program, but he may get caught the case and when it has influence and according to your answer he will not think about it and it will lead to a deterioration of his program.